# How to include image in email template using pug and img tag?

Tags: javascript, pug

Whenever the email is sent to the user, the image isn't loaded and the alt text appears. This is the img tag that appears in the inspector whenever i open the email in the browser.

```html
<img src="https://ci6.googleusercontent.com/proxy/Pm5tpNLIinvz0p0dF6dbHpM750__JhW0ZV1huQqVFnM-34fg8W7Gc67CBT0WUZWWBQ-gbCw=s0-d-e1-ft#http://static/images/DJiotitle.png" alt="DataJoint Databasee Setup" width="450" style="display:block" class="CToWUd" jslog="138226; u014N:xr6bB; 53:W2ZhbHNlXQ..">
```

[image: Here is my file directory]

Here is the line of code within the codebase that contains the img tag

```
img(src='static/images/DJiotitle.png', alt='DataJoint Databasee Setup', width='450', style='display: block;')
```

I'm thinking that this has to do with sending the email and having the browser find the image whenever it arrives. I've tried researching img tag issues whenever sending emails using templates with pug and i haven't found anything that could help me with this. I've also tried using different paths such as /static, static/, but no such luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I need to use the url that is publicly available within the source.

Comment: https://support.google.com/mail/thread/71416370/email-images-not-loading-through-usercontent-proxy?hl=en